# How to concat two observable arrays into a single array?

Tags: rxjs, observable

example:

```
var s1 = Observable.of([1, 2, 3]);

var s2 = Observable.of([4, 5, 6]);

s1.merge(s2).subscribe(val => {
   console.log(val);
})
```

I want to get 
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

instead of

[1,2,3]

[4,5,6]

Comment: if i did `Observable.forkJoin(s1, s2)` i will get [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`forkJoin` works wells, you just need to flatten the array of arrays :

```
const { Observable } = Rx;

const s1$ = Observable.of([1, 2, 3]);
const s2$ = Observable.of([4, 5, 6]);

Observable
  .forkJoin(s1$, s2$)
  .map(([s1, s2]) => [...s1, ...s2])
  .do(console.log)
  .subscribe();
```

Output : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Plunkr to demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/zah5XgErUmFAlMZZEu0k?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

My take is [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) and map with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pkt9wv?embed=1&file=index.ts

```
import { zip, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const s1$ = of([1, 2, 3]);
const s2$ = of([4, 5, 6]);
const s3$ = of([7, 8, 9]);
...

zip(s1$, s2$, s3$, ...)
  .pipe(
    map(res => [].concat(...res)),
    map(res => res.sort())
  )
  .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just instead of `Observable.of` use `Observable.from` that takes as argument an array and reemits all its values:

```
var s1 = Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);
var s2 = Observable.from([4, 5, 6]);

s1.merge(s2).subscribe(val => {
   console.log(val);
});
```

Maybe instead of `merge` you might want to prefer `concat` but in this situation with plain arrays it'll give same results.

This will give you:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

If you want this as a single array you could append also `toArray()` operator. Btw, you could achieve the same with `Observable.of` but you'd have to call it with `Observable.of.call(...)` which is probably unnecessary complicated and it's easier to use just `Observable.from()`.

Comment: what if you have an array of observable arrays? i.e (s1, s2, ..., sN)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could do this with List instead of Array:

```
var s1 = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3); 
var s2 = Rx.Observable.of(4, 5, 6);
```

and then

```
Rx.Observable.merge(s1,s2).toArray().map(arr=>arr.sort()).su‌​scribe(x=>console.l‌​og(x))
```

Comment: my sources are arrays, so thats not an option for me

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer from @maxime1992 will now cause deprecation warnings with the current version of RXJS. Here's an updated version:

```
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const s1$ = of([1, 2, 3]);
const s2$ = of([4, 5, 6]);

Observable
  .forkJoin([s1$, s2$])
  .pipe(     
    .map(([s1, s2]) => [...s1, ...s2])
  )
.do(console.log)
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular version 13, you can use `forkJoin` as follows:

```
import { forkJoin, of, map  } from 'rxjs';

const s1$ = of([1, 2, 3]);
const s2$ = of([4, 5, 6]);

forkJoin([s1$, s2$])
  .pipe(     
    .map(([s1, s2]) => [...s1, ...s2])
  )
.subscribe(console.log);
```