# Angular 4 AsyncPipe don't allow me to change data

Tags: angular, rxjs

Actually i am wondering what i am doing wrong

i have this line of code in my component returns observable

```
this.items$ = this.dataFetchService.getItems();
```

and the template

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
<div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I need to push some new values to this array, they comes from other part of application, not from an api. So how exactly i can perform that? Because if i want to use push, or something like that it says that this function not existing, but what may replace it in observable?

My service is just holding some EvenetEmitters, 1 component emits and another is catching this.

Before making it with `async pipe` it was like like this

```
this.dataTransferService.newItem.subscribe(res => this.items.push(res))

this.dataFetchService.subscribe(res => this.items = res)
```

It was working fine, but i want to redesign it.

Comment: `this.items` vs `items$` , seems to be a typo

Comment: Yes, this is just a typo, I wanted to show quick brief example, my code looks different

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141569/how-to-concat-two-observable-arrays-into-a-single-array

Comment: I don't think that it is a duplicate, because I want to solve specific problem, actually I was redesigning things to use async pipe on my api calls, and got this probmlem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
 export class AppComponent  {

  items$ : Subject<any[]>;

  constructor(service:Service) {   
  }

ngOnInit(){
  Observable
  .forkJoin(this.items$, this.service.get())
  .map(([current, added]) => [...current, ...added])
  .subscribe((newData)=>{
       this.items$.next(newData)
  });
}
}
```

EDIT : use combineLatest instead of ForkJoin as pointed at by @Jota.Toledo

```
 export class AppComponent  {

  items$ : Subject<any[]>;

  constructor(service:Service) {   
  }

ngOnInit(){
  Observable
  .combineLatest(this.items$, this.service.get())
  .map(([current, added]) => [...current, ...added])
  .subscribe((newData)=>{
       this.items$.next(newData)
  });
}
}
```

Comment: actually i have 1 more Observable from a service, that i am subscribed form, thats the one that added. this service get just returning data from api call. As far as i see u just doing same stuff that i am doing right now.

Comment: Could you add more to your OP ? What are your services? return types ? expected behaviour with an example?

Comment: Close enough, use combineLatest instead of forkJoin. ForkJoin will wait for the source observables to complete before emiting a value. The subject wont complete unless you explicitly call complete on it, which would be contraproductive for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is a function in your service that changes the data in the service, and another call to the getItems().

Can you elaborate a little more on what's the situation?

Comment: I have this observable, that contains array of data, sometimes it must extended by another value from my service, just another array element, and this extension may happen many times during user interacton

Comment: Even if I need that function, what would be that?)

Comment: The point is that you're trying to change the data that is inside 
 or get from dataFetchService, no matter how you change that data, you need to call the getItems() function again, so that the new data is returned.

The place that triggers the extension should also trigger an output event that tells your component to recall the getItems.