# Unexpected behavior of RxJS operators zip, merge, forkJoin and concat

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

In [this StackBlitz ToDo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pamzb6?file=src/app/app.component.html) application, I'm writing a simple 3 column presentation based on chaining observables.

In the `AppComponent`, my observables are declared and initialized as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { forkJoin, map, merge, Observable, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Item } from './item';
import { State } from './state';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  protected allItems: Observable<Item[]>;
  protected pendingItems: Observable<Item[]>;
  protected inProgressItems: Observable<Item[]>;
  protected doneItems: Observable<Item[]>;
  protected cancelledItems: Observable<Item[]>;
  protected terminalItems: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor(protected _dataSvc: DataService) {
    this.allItems = this._dataSvc.items.asObservable();
    this.pendingItems = this.allItems.pipe(
      map((data) => data.filter((p) => p.status === State.Todo))
    );
    this.inProgressItems = this.allItems.pipe(
      map((data) => data.filter((p) => p.status === State.Doing))
    );
    this.doneItems = this.allItems.pipe(
      map((data) => data.filter((p) => p.status === State.Done))
    );
    this.cancelledItems = this.allItems.pipe(
      map((data) => data.filter((p) => p.status === State.Cancelled))
    );
    // First option
    this.terminalItems = merge(this.doneItems, this.cancelledItems);
    // Second option
    //this.terminalItems = forkJoin([this.doneItems, this.cancelledItems]).pipe(
    //  map(d => d[0].concat(d[1])));
    //);
    // Third option
    //this.terminalItems = concat(this.doneItems, this.cancelledItems);
    // Fourth option
    //this.terminalItems = zip(this.doneItems, this.cancelledItems)
    //  .pipe(map(d => d[0].concat(d[1])));
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._dataSvc.initData();
  }
}
```

As you can see in the `InMemoryDataService`, the field `allItems` gets the following content

```
let items: Item[] = [
      {id:1, name: "Eat", status: State.Todo},
      {id:2, name: "Sleep", status: State.Todo},
      {id:3, name: "Code", status: State.Todo},
      {id:4, name: "Game", status: State.Doing},
      {id:5, name: "Swim", status: State.Done},
      {id:6, name: "Bike", status: State.Cancelled},
    ];
```

The [RxJS operator decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) guided me to use `merge` to initialize the observable `terminalItems` as follows:

`this.terminalItems = merge(this.doneItems, this.cancelledItems);`

In `app.component.html`, I expected the **Terminal** `div`, to contain items of status `Cancelled` and `Done` (i.e. Bike, Swim).

However, the **Terminated** column contains only `cancelledItems`. Changing the order of the arguments of the `merge` operator makes the `doneItems` appear, but not the `cancelledItems`.

Checking the documentation and trying alternatives ([forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin), [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) and [zip](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip)), I tested how different operators produce terminated items and found the following:

- `forkJoin`: Showed no elements in Terminated column. Check Second option commented in the code, which basically tests the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141569/how-to-concat-two-observable-arrays-into-a-single-array)
- `concat`: Depending on arguments order, shows either `cancelledItems` **or** `doneItems`
- `zip`: Showed both `cancelledItems` and `doneItems`

Could someone explain why only `zip` is working as expected? although according to the documentation, `merge` looks like it must work!

Comment: Could you please share the editable version of the stackblitz?

Comment: According to the documentation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge merge would output one array, then the other. It does not concatenate the two arrays.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton 
Edited link in question to point to editable version. Here (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) it says "Flattens multiple Observables together by blending their values into one Observable." and the diagram shows that too

Comment: I believe this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144340/12914833

Comment: Yes, it blends their output into one *observable stream* not one *array*.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton  
The answer you referred to is basically option 2 in my Stackblitz and it doesn't work. Did you manage to get forkJoin to work as expected?

Comment: My mistake, it's actually `combineLatest` for observables that do not complete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `combineLatest` since `forkJoin` only fires when all observables complete.

```
    this.terminalItems = combineLatest([
      this.doneItems,
      this.cancelledItems,
    ]).pipe(map(([a, b]) => [...a, ...b]));
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1qguvv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

More info: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

You might prefer `learnrxjs.io` to the official documentation, I find it more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Merge will merge the emissions of `n` Observables. So you get two `Item[]` values, every one which will replace the previous and your ui will render the names in that array.

You can see this behaviour when you add a `delay(2000)` to the `doneItems` which will make that emission come later and overwriting the render.

To get the combined values you will have to accumulate whichever items are already there with new emissions into one array using `combineLatest`